# SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Tags: java, spring, jsf

We are getting the following exception

```
######################ContextDestroyed###################
Sep 29, 2016 5:08:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 29, 2016 5:08:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ViewMap.clear(UIViewRoot.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.release(InitFacesContext.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5063)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5719)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am unable to find the root cause. Already attempted a lot.

Comment: Can you share snippet of the code causing this issue?

Comment: Resolution invalid properties set for dbconnection.properties

Comment: Share at least your beans configurations